# How to prove $\log n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms

$$n, \frac n2,\frac n4,\frac n8,\frac n{16}\dots 1$$

In this series $n$ to $1$, there are $x$ number of steps.

Then how to prove (Can we prove?)

$\log_2 n = x$

Comment: It's quite obvious if you just reverse it

Comment: Yes, But is there a way to prove?

Comment: Yes, sure there are ways. If you know the reason behind it, it will be easy to prove it. A proof is just an argument that shows the reason behind something.

Answer (score 1):

It’s clear that after $k$ steps you have $\dfrac{n}{2^k}$; when $\dfrac{n}{2^k}=1$, clearly $n=2^k$. Now just take logs base $2$.